# PHP Based for Search Engine Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, search-engine

I'm looking for PHP based search engine framework, that similiar to Compass
http://www.compass-project.org/
But it should free and open source.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks
Ivan

Comment: where is the question ? What do you expecting from us exactly ?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html seems to match your requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No  being funny but a simple google query and an hour of research will teach you much more than having the answer handed to you on a plate. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=open+source+php+search+engine&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari